# Django method call from template sets named variable. How is this even possible?

Tags: python, django

In a view I call a method from a template like so:

```
{{ stakeholder.get_avg_endorsement|floatformat:1 }}
```

The method looks something like this:

```
def get_avg_endorsement(self, stakeholder_cache={}):
    if stakeholder_cache.has_key(self.id):
        print "gae cached:", stakeholder_cache[self.id], stakeholder_cache, locals()
        return stakeholder_cache[self.id]
    ...
```

What I would expect is for that particular call to always have an empty stakeholder_cache. However sometimes get_avg_endorsement produces a wrong value and then the print trace looks like this:

```
[Thu May 05 17:31:46 2016] [error] ot----- <- start of the view
[Thu May 05 17:31:47 2016] [error] gae cached: 1.33333333333 {5661L: 1.3333333333333333}
[Thu May 05 17:31:47 2016] [error] gae cached: 1.33333333333 {5661L: 1.3333333333333333}
[Thu May 05 17:31:47 2016] [error] gae cached: 1.33333333333 {5661L: 1.3333333333333333}
```

As you can see all of the calls to `get_avg_endorsement` have something in their `stakeholder_cache`. How is that possible when I'm calling it from the template at least once? I've used `traceback` and it shows at least one call from the template renderer.

I'm using an older version of Django (1.4.3). Could this be a bug in Django? `get_avg_endorsement` is also called from other places that does use the `stakeholder_cache`.

I've spent hours on this and I don't have the foggiest idea how this can happen or how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the parameters in your function.

```
def get_avg_endorsement(self, stakeholder_cache={})
```

This is creating problem because default parameters are always evaluated when the function is executed. For details, check:

[Default Parameter Values in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)

Do this instead:

```
def get_avg_endorsement(self, stakeholder_cache=None):
    if stakeholder_cache is None:
        stakeholder_cache ={}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That totally explains the race condition and your advice seems to have fixed the issue.